# An expected time in biased Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability

Let $N>2$ be an integer. We consider the random random $X=\{X_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ on $S=\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ with absorbing states $A=\{0,N\}$, and with
\begin{align*}
P[X_{k+1}=i+1\mid X_k=i]=p,\quad P[X_{k+1}=i-1\mid X_k=i]=q,\quad k\ge 0,\, i \in S \setminus A,\\
\end{align*}
where positive numbers $p$ and $q$ satisfy $p+q=1$ and $p\neq q$.

Let $T$ be the number of steps until $X$ is absorbed in $0$ (that is, $T=\inf\{k \ge 0 \mid X_k=0\}$). For $0 \le n\le N-1$, we define $V_n=E[T \mid X_0=n]$. We also set $V_N=\infty$ (this is  natural, right?).

It is straightforward to see
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad V_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k P[T=k \mid X_0=n],\quad 1 \le n\le N-1.
\end{align*}
Writing  $P_{n}^k=P[T=k \mid X_0=n]$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
(2)\quad P_n^{k}=pP_{n+1}^{k-1}+qP_{n-1}^{k-1},\quad 1 \le n\le N-1,\quad k\ge 1.
\end{align*}
Combining (1) and (2), we arrive at
\begin{align*}\begin{cases}
V_0=0,\quad V_N=\infty,\\
V_{n}=1+pV_{n+1}+qV_{n-1},\quad 1\le n \le N-1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

**My question.** In my calculation, $V_n=\infty$ for any $1\le n\le N$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, with finite probability, the process get's absorbed at N, and $V_N = \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"can we show from this that $V_n = \infty\quad \forall n\in[1,N-1]$"

Here's one way. Let $N \in \mathbb N$. We are given:
\begin{align*}
V_{n}&=1+pV_{n+1}+qV_{n-1},\quad 1\le n \le N-1\\
\end{align*}
from this:
\begin{align*}
V_{N-1}&=1+pV_{N}+qV_{n-1}\\
&\geq pV_{N}\\
&= \infty\\
V_{N-2}&=1+pV_{N-1}+qV_{n-3},\quad 1\le n \le N-1\\
&\geq pV_{N-1}\\
&= \infty\\
\dots
\end{align*}
We similarly show for all $V_n=\infty\quad \forall n\in[N]$. Note that this proof only works if $N$ is finite.